# Add new type of item in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to add new type of items in Oracle APEX 19.1. I need to have oportunity to use

```
<input type="number">
```

Default "Number Field" is just a

```
<input type="text" ... class="number_field ..." >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why the APEX team decided not to include the "Number" as a Subtype for a Text Field. It likely has to do with cross-browser consistency and may involve future plans for the Number Field type (perhaps that will be enhanced to better meet your needs at some point).

In the meantime, a little bit of JavaScript can achieve the desired result. Add something like this to the page level attribute **Execute when Page Loads**:

```
$('#P7_CREDIT_LIMIT').attr('type', 'number');
```

Just replace the item name with the correct one, but leave the "#" at the beginning.

Comment: In APEX 4, it was possible to select "number" as a subtype. I used JS for this, but I was looking for a dedicated method. Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the number keyboard on mobile devices? If so, just add `inputmode="numeric"` to the **Custom Attributes** field as explained by Stefan Dobre here: https://twitter.com/stefan__dobre/status/1186553984091328512

Comment: Thank you for answer but no. App is not for mobile device. I'm trying to make input type="number"